# I have implemented chartJs in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

i want to remove this horizontal scroll from my chart. how can i remove the scroll from the graph which is mentioned in picture.

thanks

[image]

html code:

```html
<canvas id="barChart" height="5" width="20"></canvas>
```

.ts code:

```js
options: {
                title: {
                    text: "Bar Chart",
                    display: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display:false,

                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display:false
                        },   
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    onHover: function (e) {
                        e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    }
                },
                hover: {
                    onHover: function (e) {
                        var point = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
                        if (point.length) e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                        else e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this

```
options : {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
     .
     .
     . 
}
```

remove the height and width in html